# How can I make one armature influence 2 others?

Tags: rigging

[image]

So I want to have this model move the whole band in one rig, but to model it I made 2 separate sides. Maybe there is some what I can apply the two sides?
For example, I would want the highlighted armature in the image to move the two other rigs.

I'm not all that experienced with armatures XD

Comment: You could bone parent those two rigs, for one.  It's kinda hard to answer this question without knowing what you've tried and how it didn't work for you.